# How to add 21 days to date picker value in android

Tags: android, datepicker

```
public void Pickdateheatdryopen(View view) {
        final Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance ();
        final int year = calender.get ( Calendar.YEAR );
        final int month = calender.get ( Calendar.MONTH );
        final int day = calender.get ( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH );
        calender.add(Calendar.DATE,5);


        datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog ( CowActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener () {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

                /*SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
final Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance ();
        final int year = calender.get ( Calendar.YEAR );
        final int month = calender.get ( Calendar.MONTH );
        final int day = calender.get ( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH );
        calender.add(Calendar.DATE,5);                
Date s = calender.getTime();
                Log.e(TAG,"vale"+sdf.format(s));*/

                inputheatdry.setText ( (dayOfMonth) + "/" + (month+1 ) + "/" + (year) );
               // read1 ();
            }

        }, year, month, day );
        datePickerDialog.show ();
    }
```

I tried like above but I didn't get the exact output.i have used calender object and set the value but I am not getting to add days to picker value.

Comment: What you want in output? Can you please mention it? @Mounika

Comment: Do you want a minimum of 21 days?

Comment: output is date picker date + 21 days

Answer (score 2):

First add 21 days to your calendar then fetch and set the year, month & day to your `DatePickerDialog` in following manner :

```
final Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance ();
 calender.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,21);
 final int year = calender.get ( Calendar.YEAR );
 final int month = calender.get ( Calendar.MONTH );
 final int day = calender.get ( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

This will show 21st date selected in `DatePickerDialog` from today (e.g. for 20th june2019, 11th July 2019 will be selected)

UPDATED (To add 21 days after date selection from DatePickerDialog):

```
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
            final Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
            calender.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
            calender.set(Calendar.MONTH,month);
            calender.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,dayOfMonth);
            calender.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,21);
            Date s = calender.getTime();
            Log.e(TAG, "vale" + sdf.format(s));
            // read1 ();
        }
```

Comment: No I want to add after use pick date from picker

Comment: Then move above code in _onDateSet()_ method after user selected the date.

Comment: That's also easy to achieve, just add 21 days in the values received in `onDateSet()`, have updated the answer, please check

Comment: @Mounika I think Astha posted it correctly. Have you solved it?

Comment: @PratikDasa, please consider upvoting the solution if you find it correct. Thanks.

Comment: For sure @Astha as problem was not mine but I found it is right so will do!

Answer (score 0):

you have to do like below

```
public void Pickdateheatdryopen(View view) {

        final Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance ();
        calender.add(Calendar.DATE,21);

        final int year = calender.get ( Calendar.YEAR );
        final int month = calender.get ( Calendar.MONTH );
        final int day = calender.get ( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH );



        datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog ( CowActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener () {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

                inputheatdry.setText ( (dayOfMonth) + "/" + (month+1 ) + "/" + (year) );
               // read1 ();
            }

        }, year, month, day );
        datePickerDialog.show ();
    }
```

Before you get the `day` from `calendar` object you have to add days in the `calendar`.

**Note:** It will add days from the current date.

**Update**

```
public void Pickdateheatdryopen(View view) {

            String oldDate = "2017-01-29";  
            System.out.println("Date before Addition: "+oldDate);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
            try{
                calender.setTime(sdf.parse(oldDate));
             }catch(ParseException e){
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }

            calender.add(Calendar.DATE,21);

            final int year = calender.get ( Calendar.YEAR );
            final int month = calender.get ( Calendar.MONTH );
            final int day = calender.get ( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH );



            datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog ( CowActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener () {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

                    inputheatdry.setText ( (dayOfMonth) + "/" + (month+1 ) + "/" + (year) );
                   // read1 ();
                }

            }, year, month, day );
            datePickerDialog.show ();
        }
```

Comment: not for current date , I want to add for the date picker date